# Specificity order of CSS tag selectors with equal specificity

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

While refreshing my knowledge of the basics of HTML and CSS, I looked into the rules for specificity as outlined on the [W3 website](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity-rules), as well as [Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and several tutorials sites. However, none of them appear to explain the behavior that I encountered here.

```css
h1{
    color: blue;
}

body{
    color: yellow
}

div{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>This is the title</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No matter the ordering of the CSS rules shown above, the h1 always turns blue. When commenting out the h1 rule, the h1 always turns red, no matter the ordering. This clearly seems to indicate that the priority for applying these rules is h1 > div > body.

While that makes much intuitive sense, after all, the h1 is more specific than selecting the entire body, their 'formal' specificity should be exactly the same (0,0,1) in which case the rules should be applied by ['Source order'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#Understanding_the_cascade) according to Mozilla.org.

Can anyone explain to me if I'm making mistakes in interpretation here? To me it seems that source order seems to indicate that the code above should show the title in red. Even though I would agree that the current behavior is perhaps more intuitive (with an h1 seeming more intuitively specific than a div), I'd be very happy if someone could point me in the direction of the formal definition of these rules, because the specifity rules don't seem to explain this adequately.

Comment: we only talk about specificity when all the selectors target the same element

Comment: from the first duplicate : *Any declaration that matches element directly will get priority over the property that's inherited from the element's parent. Specificity has nothing to do with that.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specificity matters when two or more selectors are matching the same element – not the case here.

e.g.:
in the example below the more specific selector `div#id.class` won't win against `h1` because they are referring to two distinct elements, so the color of `h1` is determined by the first rule

```css
h1{
    color: blue;
}

   
div#id.class {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="id" class="class">
        <h1>This is the title</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the lightning fast answer. Very obvious explanation. Should probably have realized this myself ;). So basically, would I be correct in saying that a css rule always overrides inheritance, no matter the specificity?

Comment: yes, that's the result.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the tag, but the closest node in the DOM that matters.

```css
h1{
    color: blue;
}

body{
    color: yellow
}

div{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <div>
            This is the title
        </div>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```